# PHP / MySQL - Constructing a Query

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to put together a SQL query and its got me all confused, i have written out in normal language what i need, i cant seem to get it.

```
select * from introles where introle = $key 
then check the table 'availability' for the user_id taken from the introles table
then out of those results, check that $_POST['date'] is not equal to the date in the 'availability' table
```

Any help would be amazing :)

EDIT: The table structure is as follows

Table introles has the following

```
id
user_id
introle
```

Table availability has the following

```
id
user_id
date
```

Comment: can you dump a structure listing of the tables in question and the key elements / criteria you are going against... it will better help writing out the query you need.

Comment: I have edited it, i hope it helps

Comment: constructing ... you mean the frenching version of building?

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
'$variable'
```

instead of

```
 $variable
```

for all variables in sql query?

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT a.id AS aId, i.id AS iId, a.user_id, introle, date FROM availability AS a, introle AS i WHERE date != {$_POST['date']} AND a.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM introle WHERE introle = {$key})";
```